# How to play video in phaser 3 framework?

Tags: phaser-framework

I don't know to play video with Phaser v3 framework. I was tried some ways but it don't work. Anyone help me pls.

this.load.video('myVideo1', 'assets/video/video1.mp4');

Comment: Hi there is a video support for Phser 2 (CE) but actually not yet for Phaser 3 so I've found a repo on GitHub that implements video so I will work on a plugin inspired from it https://github.com/nazimboudeffa/phaser3-video it's really the begining and doesn't work at the moment am writing this comment

Answer (score 2):

For Phaser 3, the video support is only for v3.20 or upper: https://phaser.io/download/release/3.20.0

```
function preload (){
    this.load.video('video', '../assets/videos/video.webm');
}
function create (){
    this.video = this.add.video(0, 0, 'video');
    this.video.play();
}
```